# For loop and if statements acting odd

Tags: java, for-loop, point, chess

I am making a chess game and so far everything is good and I am writing the rules of each piece now. The problem is that a for loop is acting oddly. Its for the bishop so x is going down and y is going up. At this point it acts oddly whenever I try to add the point to a possible move

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   Point newLoc = new Point(x-i, y+i);              

  if(team.equals("white")) {
    if(containsPiece(newLoc)) {
            if(ChessBoard.black.containsKey(newLoc)) {
                possibilities.put(newLoc, rating);
                break;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        } else 
            possibilities.put(newLoc, rating);
    }
```

`containsPiece()` is working just fine and `possibilities` is the `HashMap` I am storing the possible moves in.

The way I see it it should be working perfect because if the tile at `newLoc` is white it shouldn't add it to the possible moves and stop getting any moves after it in that direction. Does anyone see why it seems to abandon all the previous possible moves added to `possibilities`

[image: What it should look like]

[image: What it is looking like with the code above]

Comment: Why is there a break in both clauses of the inner most if/else?

Comment: You break out of the loop as soon as you discover a black piece - both branches have a `break`.

Comment: The black needs a break that way it doesn't add any pieces after that one and the white needs it, so it doesn't allow a white piece to take a white piece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` should start in `1`, not `0`, since when `i==0`, `newLoc` is the position of the bishop (`(x-0,y+0)`), so you break from the loop, since the bishop is a white tile.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. I didn't even think of that. Thanks